# SQL query 3 columns, count 1 and group only another one

Tags: sql, count, grouping, distinct

this is my table

```
names   city    food
jim  | london  | pizza
jim  | london  | burrito
anne | paris   | croissant
tim  | berlin  | wurst
tim  | berlin  | schnitzel
tim  | berlin  | beer
```

I would like to count the distinct cities and group by name but get only one food entry:

```
jim, 2, pizza
anne, 1, croissant
tim, 3, wurst
```

but this doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, food, COUNT(city) AS cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Best
Joerg

Comment: *distinct cities* then why jim, 2?

Comment: Good sample data is a part of the solving process. Why does all your persons only have one distinct city each, at least one of the should have been to two cities.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below according to outcome it seems you just need max() aggregate function with your esisting query

```
select name, max(food), COUNT(city) AS cnt
FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thx! I did select DISTINCT name, max(food), COUNT(city) AS cnt
FROM mytable GROUP BY name   and then it worked!